# Long IF-ELSE vectorized DataFrame creation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Is there a way to vectorize the following in a `DataFrame`:

```
d = a.diff()
out = d >=0 and a > b ? 0 : d < 0 and a > b ? 1 : d <= 0 and a < b ? 2 : d >= 0 and a < b ? 3 : 4
```

Here, both `a` and `b` are a simple timeseries in the form of a `DataFrame` or `Series` with unimportant data. In my test files I generate them as such:

```
range = pd.date_range('2019-01-01', freq='MS', periods=10)
a = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(20, size=(10, 1)), 
                  columns=['value'], 
                  index=range)
```

. What I thought about doing was using `map()` to something that looks like this:

```
out = (
        (d >= 0) & (a > b)
).map({
    True: 0,
    False: (
            (d < 0) & (a > b)
    ).map({ ...
```

This is of course not correct, because of the `False` case, but hopefully you get the idea.

How can I vectorize this complex statement into a DataFrame?

Comment: What is `b`? Can you provide a MRE?

Comment: @PierreD, edited with more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### TL;DR

Yes, you can, but you need to be very clear about *all* the cases.

#### Details

There are a couple of issues with the tests themselves:

1. `d = a.diff()` means the first element of `d` is `NaN`. All the tests against a constant will return `False` (even `d == d` is `False` for the first element, which BTW is the canonical way to check for a `NaN` value).
2. Your tests are not neatly separable into two independent tests (e.g. `a < b` on one hand an `d < 0` on the other). Is that intentional? It sure complicates things.

First, let's express your conditions as Python ternary equivalents:

```py
out = [
    0 if d >= 0 and a > b else
    1 if d < 0 and a > b else
    2 if d <= 0 and a < b else
    3 if d >= 0 and a < b else
    4 for a, b, d in zip(a.squeeze(), b.squeeze(), d.squeeze())
]
```

Obviously, that isn't vectorized.

#### One (of many) vectorized solution

To vectorize such an expression, let's look at the values table:

|  | `a < b` | `a == b` | `a > b` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **`d < 0`** | 2 | 4 | 1 |
| **`d == 0`** | 2 | 4 | 0 |
| **`d > 0`** | 3 | 4 | 0 |
| **`d.isna()`** | 4 | 4 | 4 |

You can express that as a sum of simple cases:

- Handle 4 separately (`a == b or d.isna()`).
- For the rest, it is largely 2 for the left column, and 0 for the right column, *plus*
- `a < b` XOR `d < 0`, and finally,
- an override for `a < b` and `d == 0`, which should get 2.

You can get a vectorized implementation of that table (note: I'm just using the `numpy` arrays for concision):

```py
a_lt_b = a <= b
d_lt_0 = d < 0
d_isna = np.isna(d)
a_eq_b = a == b

out2 = a_lt_b * 2 + (d_lt_0 ^ a_lt_b)
out2[a_lt_b & (d == 0)] = 2
out2[d_isna | a_eq_b] = 4
```

Verification

```py
a = np.tile([-1, 0, 1], 4)
b = np.zeros_like(a)
d = np.repeat([np.nan, -1, 0, 1], 3)
out = [
    0 if d >= 0 and a > b else
    1 if d < 0 and a > b else
    2 if d <= 0 and a < b else
    3 if d >= 0 and a < b else
    4 for a, b, d in zip(a, b, d)
]

# visualization
def view(df, valname='out'):
    df = df.assign(c1='a == b', c2='d == 0')
    df.loc[df.a < df.b, 'c1'] = 'a < b'
    df.loc[df.a > df.b, 'c1'] = 'a > b'
    df.loc[df.d < 0, 'c2'] = 'd < 0'
    df.loc[df.d > 0, 'c2'] = 'd > 0'
    df.loc[df.d.isna(), 'c2'] = 'd.isna()'
    return df.set_index(['c1', 'c2'])[valname].unstack('c1')
```

After the calculation of `out2` above:

```py
z = pd.DataFrame(dict(a=a, b=b, d=d, out=out, out2=out2))

>>> np.array_equal(z['out'], z['out2'])

>>> view(z, 'out2')  # same as for 'out'
c1        a < b  a == b  a > b
c2                            
d < 0         2       4      1
d == 0        2       4      0
d > 0         3       4      0
d.isna()      4       4      4
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the equivalent `lambda` and `np.vectorize()` would be of use?

```
# out = d >=0 and a > b ? 0 : d < 0 and a > b ? 1 : d <= 0 and a < b ? 2 : d >= 0 and a < b ? 3 : 4
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

out = lambda a, b, d: 0 if d >= 0 and a > b else 1 if d < 0 and a > b else 2 if d <= 0 and a < b else 3 if d >= 0 and a < b else 4

out = np.vectorize(out)

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3}, 'B': {0: 5, 1: 4, 2: 3}, 'C': {0: 4, 1: 4, 2: 4}})

print(out(df['A'], df['B'], df['C']))
```

Results:

```
[3 3 4]
```